# Is it possible to have two different 95% confidence intervals from two meta-analyses on the same original article?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, meta-analysis

I'm confused about the two different recalculated 95% confidence interval (CI) results from two meta-analyses on the same article.

The original article reported **a geometric mean of 2.3 and a geometric standard deviation (SD) of 1.60.**

However, **one meta-analysis** calculated a 95% CI of **0.76-3.84** using these values, while **another meta-analysis** reported a 95% CI of **2.03-2.57**.

How is it possible for two different meta-analyses on the same original article to produce two different 95% confidence intervals?
Thank you for reading this :)

Comment: What was the sample size of the reported statistics?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The original article had a sample size (n) of 133.

Comment: Thank you. Can you link to the two meta-analyses?

Comment: The second one is easy: It's just the 95% confidence interval around the value: $2.3 \pm 1.96\frac{1.6}{\sqrt{144}}$. But I can't reproduce the first confidence interval.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. For the second one, is it appropriate to use a formula to calculate a geometric confidence interval from a geometric mean and SD? I believe that this formula works well in a normal distribution, for which the authors of the second one used log-transformation and then transformed the log values back into geometric values. Therefore, to calculate the upper limit of a geometric 95% confidence interval, I think the formula would be: exp(ln(2.3) + 1.96 * ln(1.6) / sqrt(133)).

Comment: I think you are correct, although you mention they had $n = 144$ instead of $n= 133$.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help! Your contribution will be acknowledged in my study.

Comment: Additionally, I am not sure where the value of 4.15 came from, but it seems like it was used in all of the categories instead of the sample size. Another meta-analysis used the formula 2.3 +/- (1.96*1.6/sqrt(4.15)).